# Issue between app as the shortcut and app in the menu

Tags: android

I have a problem were I launch my app go to a different activity and press home. If I press the app again it starts with the activity I recently went to. However, this only works depending on where I originally launched the app. If I use the shortcut version of my app on the home screen and go to another activity then press home and then go to the app menu version where my app is located, I get sent to the main activity and not from the activity I recently went to. Is there any solutions to this?

Comment: Setting android:launchMode in your manifest might help you here. Take a look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) and read about the different ways Android handles launching your activity. I think you need "singleTop", but it's probably best to try out all the possible values.